# How to change maximum item durability in Minecraft?(No Enchantment)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to change maximum item’s durability in Minecraft, but without enchantments. I want to use /give command. How can I do this? Is it possible to do?

Here is my first trial:

```
give @p diamond_pickaxe{Enchantments:[{id:unbreaking,lvl:10}]}
```

Comment: When you say "change durability", do you mean "change the maximum durability" or "change how much the item has been used out of its max durability"?

Comment: I want to change item durability value.

Comment: Just saying "item durability" isn't clear. You either want to change the *maximum durability level on an item*, or you want to change *how much the item has been used out of its max durability*. Please choose which one.

Comment: Change the maximum durability on an item.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the NBT tag, `Damage` to give you an item with damage on it. Since a diamond pickaxe has 1561 durability, the command `/give @p diamond_pickaxe{Damage:50}` would give you a diamond pickaxe with 1511 durability left.

If you wish to change the durability of an existing item, you can use `/data merge entity @e[type=item,distance=..3,limit=1] {Item:{tag:{Damage:0}}}` to set the durability of an item that is dropped on the ground

Comment: Can I change an item's durability without any damage to item?

Comment: Yes, by using the second method and a but of subtraction, you can change the durability of any item while keeping everything else the same

Comment: I want to use /give command

Comment: You can then use the `Damage` tag how I used it in the first example

Comment: I want to use one give command and I want to change an item's durability without any damage to item. Can you help me?

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here, the `Damage` tag _is_ how much the item has been used, so the durability is the `total durability - damage = durability left`

Comment: Oh sorry, But I want to change the maximum value. Sorry about this.

Comment: Can you help me to change the maximum value?

Comment: There is no way to change the maximum durability of an item in Minecraft, you're stuck with the default tool durabilities

Comment: Thank you for this answer and this comment :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112767/discussion-between-macks-and-arian).

Comment: So could we use **negative** damage to increase the item durability?

Comment: @fasterthanlight If you use a tag such as `{Damage:-50}` the durability is just set to full.